Comparison of algebras
Given a an algebra $\mathfrak{U}_d=\mathrm{Alg}(G,G^\dagger)$ for $G$ being a finite set of finite-dimensional linearly independent unitary matrices, so $\mathfrak{U}_d$ is a the set of polynomials constructed by $G$ and being a self-adjoint C*-algebra having dimension $d$
Now, I want this algebra $\mathfrak{U}_d$=$\mathfrak{sl}_d$, $\mathfrak{sl}_d$ denoting the special linear Lie algebra.
What requirements do I have to give $G$ and its elements such that this is fulfilled? I failed to find reference dealing with this, in general I cannot really find anything dealing with generating sets of algebras.
